# Choosing an initial guess for g(x) in solving a Differential Equation using Undetermined Coefficients.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Question is to solve the differential equation using Undetermined Coefficients:

Equation:

$x'' = -6t - te^{-t}$

Why is this the correct initial guess of g(x)?

$At{^3} +(Bt +C) e^{-t} $

From the Table of Initial Guesses for a particular solution. I would have used:

$ At+B + (Ct +D) e^{-t} $
which is incorrect.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Because when differentiating $At+B$ **twice,** it vanishes and there is nothing left to accommodate de $t^3$ in your O.D.E.

Comment: My question rather is, how does one know that the ODE requires $t^{3}$ to begin with

Comment: Because you need second derivative to have $t$ so the orignal function needs $t^3$ . Remember that you can sums the solutions since this is a linear equation. Also if you had applied to undetermined coefficient properly you'd found a good solution too.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, would that not mean that every single g(x) that has a a 1st order variable like 5x+7 will have a guess that has $x^{3} $? Look at this table https://i.stack.imgur.com/aprWe.png , from it, the guess would be (Ax+B)

Comment: @ZaheedaChauke But the second derivative is $At+b=-6t$. So you need the function that you integrate two times: $\int \int At+B \ dt \ dt=C_3t^3+C_2t^2+C_1t+C_0=g(t)$

Comment: Because it is an initial value problem here you need the initial values $x(0)$ and $x'(0)$:
$$x\! \left(t\right)=\left(-t-2\right) {\mathrm e}^{-t}-t^{3}+\left(x'(0)-1\right) t+x(0)+2$$

Comment: @callculus42 Thank you, I get it. Could you post your comment as an answer